# How do you update a composer project version?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-6

I've made a project file based on Laravel 6 which introduces a lot of specific-to-me functionality including things such as generic views under resources and overrides to the Controller Class in App/Http.

I've uploaded the project to GitHub and added it to packagist so that I can create projects with all the custom stuff in the future using the `composer create-project` command but what I can't seem to work out is how once created from this method how I'd go about upgrading a project created from the `composer create-project` method to a new version with new additions (which will mostly be new views and functions for the Controllers as mentioned earlier).

What is the best/standard method for updating a composer project for the latest version to gain the changes/additions in the App or Resources folders?

Comment: Can you post the link to the packagist project, for better understanding. And how about simply editing your dependency version and run `composer update`?

Answer (score 0):

Updating stuff with Composer usually is done via CLI like this:

```
composer require "vendor/lib:^2.0" "vendor2/lib:^3.0" --update-with-dependencies
```

You simply have to figure out which new version requirements you want, and possibly you have to try more than one time. But in the end your existing project has upgraded libraries once Composer finishes without complaint.

Note that `--update-with-dependencies` will allow Composer to update any library that isn't constrained otherwise. This will affect you in no way if you declared your dependencies correctly, i.e. explicitly declared every package you use in your production code.

To check if you do, use `composer-require-checker` https://packagist.org/packages/maglnet/composer-require-checker